# 4 digit Miller Index for a cubic structure?

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals

As the title states, can a [Miller index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_index) for a cubic structure have 4 digits? If I have a structure with intercepts (2,8,3) on the x-y-z axes respectively, the following Miller index would be (12,3,8), which is not 3 digits.

Comment: what do you mean by 4 digit Miller Index?

Answer (score 1):

Four digit Miller index is sometimes used for hexagonal lattices. The idea is to have useful property: permutation of indexes gives an equivalent direction.

It is [mentioned](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_index#Case_of_hexagonal_and_rhombohedral_structures) in wikipedia, by the way. So you could start from there.

Four-digit Miller indexes are never used for cubic structure. If you could provide the citation where you saw them the answer could be better.

Comment: In a hexagonal context I found this 1917 (!) paper using four-digit indices: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1091290/

Answer (score 0):

We need to be clear about the distinction between *integers* and *digits*. Miller indices may have an infinite number of digits, but they are always composed of three integers, each of which may be arbitralily large, and therefore take a large number of digits to write down (exception: hexagonal structures sometimes use four integers). A Miller index of (12,3,8) is perfectly fine in a cubic system!